# Consuming java web service through .net - data inconsistence

Tags: c#, java, .net, web-services

I have a Java project ( a voting system ) in which I implemented a web service.

My getResults method returns a String[]. If the voting is done the method returns the array populated with 'Item 1 - 2 votes, Item 2 - 3 Votes...'. If it isn't, it returns the array with a single string saying that voting is still on.

The problem is that if i call getResults from within my java application it works as expected but if i call it from my webservice it always returns that the voting is still on and never the results.

I'm consuming this web service through a c# console application is visual studio.

I'm pretty new to web services so let me ask this. When I instantiate my service like this:

`ServerService ss = new ServerService();`

Does it create a new instance of my class `Server()` in my Java application or is it just a way to connect to my current instance?

Well I hope I've explained my problem well and hope you can help me.

Thanks and merry xmas :)

Edit:

this is the method that is accessed by the web service

```
public String[] getResults() throws RemoteException {
    if (ended) {
        return results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);
    } else {
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        temp.add("Voting is still on");
        return temp.toArray(new String[temp.size()]);
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://backend.ve"
xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://backend.ve" xmlns:intf="http://backend.ve" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://backend.ve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <element name="getResults">
    <complexType/>
   </element>
   <element name="getResultsResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="getResultsReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="getResultsRequest">
      <wsdl:part element="impl:getResults" name="parameters">
      </wsdl:part>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="getResultsResponse">
      <wsdl:part element="impl:getResultsResponse" name="parameters">
      </wsdl:part>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="Server">
      <wsdl:operation name="getResults">
         <wsdl:input message="impl:getResultsRequest" name="getResultsRequest">
       </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output message="impl:getResultsResponse" name="getResultsResponse">
       </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="ServerSoapBinding" type="impl:Server">
      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="getResults">
         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
         <wsdl:input name="getResultsRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output name="getResultsResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="ServerService">
      <wsdl:port binding="impl:ServerSoapBinding" name="Server">
         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/VE/services/Server"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

C#:

```
namespace WSTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServerService ss = new ServerService();
            foreach (String s in ss.getResults())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code line: **ServerService ss = new ServerService();** 
creates a new object of your proxy class, which got created in your visual studio application when you have added the service reference.

Now this object will call your webmethod.

Can you post some part of your service? Are there more than one method?

Comment: added the webmethod to my post, do you need to see the wsdl ?

Comment: Yes, along with that few more things: 1. ended value (this I guess must be independent of caller) 2. WSDL 3. C# code which is calling this service. 4. Binding details etc

Comment: see above the wsdl and c# code. ended is true if the voting is done ( it has a time limit ) and false if it is still going. I think the problem is not in the c# code as i have tested it with eclipse integrated tool for web services and the same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

It does only instantiate a C# proxy for your service - an automatically generated class by .NET with all the behind-the-scenes code to manage communication with your service.

I would advice you to test your service with a tool like SoapUI before trying to integrate it with .NET and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: tested it with Eclipse tool 'Test with Web Services Explorer' and the same thing happens so the problem should be in my java application

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to figure out the exact issue in your code, but here are some pointers which will help you to sort it out.

1. Your method is not returning the string, see WSDL:

> ```
> <wsdl:operation name="getResults">
>      <wsdl:input message="impl:getResultsRequest" name="getResultsRequest">
>    </wsdl:input>
>      <wsdl:output message="impl:getResultsResponse" name="getResultsResponse">
>    </wsdl:output>
>   </wsdl:operation>
> ```

But you are expecting string as output in your C# code.

2 . You need to create two objects at C# end namely : getResultsRequest and getResultsResponse

I know you are getting same error through Eclipse, but since your service works fine when you call it from Java client. So your service logic is correct. Now only place where problem might occur is the communication between your service and client.

So my suggested C# code would be:

```
namespace WSTest
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServerService ss = new ServerService();
        getResultRequest request = new getResultRequest();
        getResultResponse response = new getResultResponse();
        response = ss.getResultResponse(request);
        // Do something with response.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is related with the ended variable as it is a global variable because i need to use it across various methods. I've changed my method to do a simple if else with a local variable and it works fine. I'm guessing that a web accessed method can't make use of the global variables ? Is there any way of dealing with this ?

Comment: It's always better to avoid global variables. If you want to access some value across application then create a property with no setter.That way you can ensure that no-one is changing your value.